# Selecting options from different divs

Tags: jquery

Here is my working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exlondoner/YvPg9/
What I'm trying to achieve is being able to select (outline) one option from Media Type and one item from Sort By, how would I do this?

JS:

```js
$('.media-select-option').on('click', function() {
 $(this).addClass('selected');
$('.overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked');    
});
```

html:

```html
<div class="overlaymedia">
<div class='media-filter'>
    <div class="media-nav" role='contentinfo'>
        <div class="media-nav media-menu-container">

            <h5 class="media-menu-heading close-overlay-btn">Media Type</h5>
            <!-- Media Type: All/Photos/Videos -->
            <div class="media-select-option media-all" data-href="">All</div>
            <div class="media-select-option media-photos" data-href="">Photos</div>
            <div class="media-select-option media-videos" data-href="">Videos</div>

            <h5 class="media-menu-heading close-overlay-btn">Sort By</h5>
            <!-- Sort By: Latest/Popular -->
            <div class="media-select-option media-latest" data-href="">Latest</div>
            <div class="media-select-option media-popular" data-href="">Popular</div>
            <div class="media-menu-bottom close-overlay-btn">
                <div class="overlay-close-btn bottom">Close</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```css
.overlay-close-btn:before { content: '×'; }

.overlay-close-btn.checked:before {
content: '✔';
}
.media-select-option {
border: solid 1px #fff;  
}
.selected {
border: solid 1px #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting your option in different `div`'s like that :

```
<div>
    <div class="media-select-option media-all" data-href="">All</div>
    <div class="media-select-option media-photos" data-href="">Photos</div>
    <div class="media-select-option media-videos" data-href="">Videos</div>
</div>

<h5 class="media-menu-heading close-overlay-btn">Sort By</h5>
<!-- Sort By: Latest/Popular -->
<div>
    <div class="media-select-option media-latest" data-href="">Latest</div>
    <div class="media-select-option media-popular" data-href="">Popular</div>
</div>
```

You then will be able to achieve what you want by doing :

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YvPg9/3/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/YvPg9/2/

And I would also recommend using a more semantic markup. If there is a need of choosing one option and not others - simply use `input[type="radio"]` with a propper `label`.

In my opinion - your markup should look something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/YvPg9/5/